# How can I find out which tables use reference partitioning from the Oracle data dictionary?

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I'm writing a generic drop-all-objects script for our Oracle databases.  It generates `drop table TABLE_NAME cascade constraints purge` lines for all tables, amongst other object types, by looping through `user_objects`.

The problem is that tables which are have reference-partitioned tables dependent on them can't be dropped in this way: `ORA-14656: cannot drop the parent of a reference-partitioned table`.

How can I detect which tables are the parents of reference partitioned tables from the data dictionary, so I can skip them in the first loop, and drop them in a second loop?

Comment: `ALL_DEPENDENCIES` doesn't seem to contain these types of dependency!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a list of partitioned tables that have at least one referencing partitioned child table the `[dba][all][user]_part_tables` and `[dba][all][user]_constrains` data dictionary views, depending on the privileges granted, can be queried:

```
create table tb_part_parent(
  col  number primary key,
  col2 number
)
partition by range (col2) (
  partition part_1 values less than (100),
  partition part_2 values less than (300),
  partition part_3 values less than (500)
)

create table tb_part_child(
  col  number not null,
  col2 number,
  constraint fk_parent_1 foreign key(col) references tb_part_parent(col)
)partition by reference (fk_parent_1)
```

The query:

```
select t.table_name
  from user_constraints t
 where t.constraint_name in ( select w.r_constraint_name
                                from user_constraints w
                                join user_part_tables q
                                  on (q.table_name = w.table_name and
                                      q.ref_ptn_constraint_name = w.constraint_name)
                              )
```

Result:

```
TABLE_NAME
-----------------
TB_PART_PARENT
```